# Using dataannotations displayFormat to change to title case in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is it possible to use Dataannotations to specify that fields display as title case rather then all upper?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why don't you just convert the text to title case in a view model?

Comment: Was just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: No, you can't use DisplayFormat attribute for that purpose. But, there are other ways to do that. For example, you can create an Html Helper, or you can create a DisplayTemplate for string type.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the display name of a particualr field, just add the `[DisplayName("DisplayedName")]` data annotation to a property in your model.

For example, if your model has the property "FirstName", you may want to display it with a space and a colon as in "First Name:" as seen here:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[DisplayName("First Name:")]
```